# Websphere datasource configuration in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, migration, websphere, datasource, rad

I'm trying to migrate J2EE, very heavy, old school application, from RAD 8.5.5.1 to IntelliJ 2016.1.1. DataSource building using JNDI. 
I compiled and configured all components (right for now) except DataSource. 
In RAD DataSource configured like this, in resource.xml:

```
<resources.jdbc:JDBCProvider xmi:id="JDBCProvider_1163951110780" name="DB2 DataSource" description="DB2 Universal JDBC Driver Provider" implementationClassName="com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2ConnectionPoolDataSource">
<classpath>${DB2UNIVERSAL_JDBC_DRIVER_PATH}/db2jcc.jar</classpath>
<classpath>${UNIVERSAL_JDBC_DRIVER_PATH}/db2jcc_license_cu.jar</classpath>
<classpath>${DB2UNIVERSAL_JDBC_DRIVER_PATH}/db2jcc_license_cisuz.jar</classpath>
<nativepath>${DB2UNIVERSAL_JDBC_DRIVER_NATIVEPATH}</nativepath>
<factories xmi:type="resources.jdbc:DataSource" xmi:id="DataSource_1163951270521" name="pensionjndi" jndiName="pensionjndi" description="DB2 Universal Driver Datasource" category="" authDataAlias="sec" relationalResourceAdapter="builtin_rra" statementCacheSize="150" datasourceHelperClassname="com.ibm.websphere.rsadapter.DB2UniversalDataStoreHelper">
  <propertySet xmi:id="J2EEResourcePropertySet_1163951270522">
    <resourceProperties xmi:id="J2EEResourceProperty_1163951270523" name="databaseName" type="java.lang.String" value="value" description="This is a required property. This is an actual database name, and its not the locally catalogued database name. The Universal JDBC Driver does not rely on information catalogued in the DB2 database directory." required="true"/>
    <resourceProperties xmi:id="J2EEResourceProperty_1163951270524" name="driverType" type="java.lang.Integer" value="4" description="The JDBC connectivity-type of a data source. If you want to use type 4 driver, set the value to 4. If you want to use type 2 driver, set the value to 2. On WAS z/OS, driverType 2 uses RRS and supports 2-phase commit processing." required="true"/>
    <resourceProperties xmi:id="J2EEResourceProperty_1163951270525" name="serverName" type="java.lang.String" value="serverName" description="The TCP/IP address or host name for the DRDA server. If custom property driverType is set to 4, this property is required." required="false"/>
    <resourceProperties xmi:id="J2EEResourceProperty_1163951270526" name="portNumber" type="java.lang.Integer" value="50000" description="The TCP/IP port number where the DRDA server resides. If custom property driverType is set to 4, this property is required." required="false"/>
...
...
...
<resourceProperties xmi:id="J2EEResourceProperty_1175088739299" name="webSphereDefaultIsolationLevel" type="java.lang.Integer" value="2" description="" required="false"/>
  </propertySet>
  <connectionPool xmi:id="ConnectionPool_1163951270521" connectionTimeout="15" maxConnections="200" minConnections="5" reapTime="180" unusedTimeout="1800" agedTimeout="0" purgePolicy="EntirePool"/>
  <mapping xmi:id="MappingModule_1163951296456" mappingConfigAlias="DefaultPrincipalMapping" authDataAlias="sec"/>
</factories>
```

I tried to define DataSource with same name (pensionjndi) using IntelliJ's DataSource and Driver window 
[DS IntelliJ Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbI9m.png)

No luck! Application doesn't recognize the DataSourse (but it looking for the RIGHT DS name "pensionjndi") 
The question is: What is a right way to configure DataSource for IntelliJ Artifacts? (Using an existing DataSources)

If an additional information required, I'll edit the post.. 
I didn't found any example, or guide, for DataSource config for websphere. 
Please HELP!?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved by defining data source in Websphere Application Console. *WAS console | Resorces | Data Sources*
See the topic of IBM "Configuring a data source using the administrative console" 
[Here is discussion about the problem with IntelliJ support](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205408250-Websphere-datasource-configuration-in-IntelliJ)